# Calling python script from C# (object-oriented approach)

Tags: c#, python

I want to run python script from C#(Visual Studio). I don't want to use C# process to do it, because I must have access to all of the python's modules, classes, and methods (I'd like to treat it as python object). I'm looking for sth like this:

"Python code"

"PyModule"

```
class PyClass:

    def method:
        print("Hello world!")
```

C# code

```
using PyModule.PyClass

PyClass.method()
```

I found python.net http://pythonnet.github.io/ , but they say that their solution is unverifiable.
I have to write it in Python 3, so IronPython isn't solution for me.

Do you know any solution that is similar to this?

Comment: You could look into [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I must use Python 3

Answer (score 1):

Well, do have a look into IronPython as suggested in the comments. You can write your python script, save it to, say, `greet.py`

```
def greet(name):
    return 'Hello ' +  name + '!'
```

Now from C# you can do:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

static void RunPythonScript()
{
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();

    engine.ExecuteFile("greeting.py", scope);
    var greeting = scope.greet("John");

    Console.WriteLine(greeting);
}
```

Result as you might expect is `Hello John!`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I have to use Python 3. I saw that IronPython3 is developed but for now it isn't tested fully so it could be a problem to use it.